# Validation failed for query method with aggregation function

Tags: spring, hibernate

I wrote this query method in Spring:

```
@Query("SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(ban.codiBanca)) FROM DBanche ban WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(ban.codiBanca, '0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL")
public BigDecimal getMaxCodiBanca();
```

Field type of codiBanca is VARCHAR(20).

When I start the application I obtain this error:

```
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.math.BigDecimal it.gov.mef.efim.dao.repository.base.BancaDao.getMaxCodiBanca()!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:136)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.AggregateNode 
 \-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'MAX'
    \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
       +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'TO_NUMBER' {originalText=TO_NUMBER}
       \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
          \-[DOT] DotNode: 'dbanche0_.CODI_BANCA' {propertyName=codiBanca,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=codiBanca,path=ban.codiBanca,tableAlias=dbanche0_,className=it.gov.mef.efim.dao.entities.DBanche,classAlias=ban}
             +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'dbanche0_.SEQU_ID_BANCA' {alias=ban, className=it.gov.mef.efim.dao.entities.DBanche, tableAlias=dbanche0_}
             \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'codiBanca' {originalText=codiBanca}
```

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: Solution: add TO_CHAR   to  MAX(TO_NUMBER(ban.codiBanca)) and return String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you seem to be using a native-query i.e. the SQL grammar is specific to the DB vendor.

So add the attribute `nativeQuery=true` to your `@Query` as below.

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value = "SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER(ban.codiBanca)) FROM DBanche ban WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(ban.codiBanca, '0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL")
public BigDecimal getMaxCodiBanca();
```

Hope this helps!

In case if you still face any issues, please post it here.

Comment: Your solution is OK !